# Adding two numbers don't get correct result

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers, addition

I try to add two numbers, but don't get correct result

```
var n1:Number =  2785077255;
var n2:Number = 100000097214922752;
trace(Number(n1 + n2));//trace 100000100000000000, not 100000100000000007
trace((Number.MAX_VALUE - Number(n1 + n2)) > 100);//trace true
```

When I got the wrong result, I thought it exceed the Number's max value,so I test it and it doesn't trace false as I thought.

Comment: You've not exceeded the maximum value, however you have exceeded the maximum *precision* of a `Number`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis so do you mean I can't the correct result just adding the numbers like this?

Comment: `Number` is a floating point representation. It is stored as a 64-bit double-precision value. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for more information. Basically it cannot store any arbitrary value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is in `Number` as @Phylogenesis mentioned, it's actually 64 bit double with 52 bits for mantis, but your result exceededs that. 
The good news are that there is a workaround for that, event two :)

1. Use some `BigInteger`/`LongInt` AS3 impelementation (you can google several of them), for instance [`BigInteger`](https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/crypto/rsa/BigInteger.as?r=3) from [as3crypto](https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/), or [`LongInt`](https://code.google.com/p/lodgamebox/source/browse/trunk/com/lordofduct/util/LongInt.as) from [lodgamebox](https://code.google.com/p/lodgamebox/)
2. It's currently only for multiplying, but you can modify that solution as a small task. For best performance (without creation of temporary arrays/byte arrays) you can use that utility method that I created once (it's based on `LongInt` from `lodgamebox` library)

   ```
   /**
    * Safe multiplying of two 32 bits uint without precision lost.  
    * 
    * Usage:
    * Default behaviour (with 64 bit Number mantis overflow): 
    *      uint(1234567890 * 134775813) = 1878152736
    * 
    * Fixed correct result by that method: 
    *      uint(1234567890 * 134775813) = 1878152730
    * 
    * @param val1
    * @param val2
    * @return 
    * 
    */
   public static function multiplyLong(val1:uint, val2:uint):uint
   {
       var resNum:Number = val1*val2;
       //52 bits of mantis in 64 bit double (Number) without loose in precision
       if(resNum <= 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
           return uint(resNum);

       //count only low 32 bits of multiplying result 
       var i:uint, mul:Number, ln:uint=0, hn:uint=0, _low:uint = val1;
       for (i = 1<<31; i; i >>>= 1)
       {
           if(val2 & i)
           {
               mul = _low * i;
               ln += mul & uint.MAX_VALUE;
           }
       }
       _low = ln;

       return _low;
   }
   ```

Comment: I got it.My Game's char id is using a 64 bit Number, and it's too hard to change the id from Number to LongInt Or  BigInteger in whole project. So the only way is to change the char id to 52 bit Number. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: or you can use a String on client side

Comment: @Pan Why not mark this as the answer, if this has helped you out?